# tiff2pdf fails with page of code

Tags: centos

Hi I am trying to use tiff2pdf to convert some tiff files captured by the fax application in asterisk to PDF

I have installed tiff2pdf by the following method:

```
sudo yum install ghostscript libtiff
```

When I execute the command to convert I get the following:

```
[root@cloud01 tmp]# tiff2pdf FAX-443439791001-2015-09-26_00-34-40.tiff
II*%PDF-1.1
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/CreationDate (D:20150926003458)
/ModDate (D:20150926003458)
/Producer (libtiff / tiff2pdf - 20100615)
/Creator (Spandsp 20110122 075024)
/Subject (01279 850795)
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Kids [ 4 0 R ]
/Count 1
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 3 0 R
/MediaBox [0.0000 0.0000 609.8823 833.8776]
/Contents 5 0 R
/Resources <<
/XObject <<
/Im1 7 0 R >>
/ProcSet [ /ImageB ]
>>
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Length 6 0 R
 >>
stream
q  609.8823 0.0000 0.0000 833.8776 0.0000 0.0000 cm /Im1 Do Q

endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
62
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/Length 8 0 R
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Name /Im1
/Width 1728
/Height 1135
/BitsPerComponent 1
/ColorSpace /DeviceGray
/Filter /CCITTFaxDecode /DecodeParms << /K -1 /Columns 1728 /Rows 1135>>
 >>
stream
ó"yËhªŠf.f)àù˜¦b™Šf))dJ†Nï…3dO<)P)àç…<ð§ƒ–îØsÁ       ó<Ÿ)ò|¾Ol¸97päù S`ä\S7™Šfág³#Ìú#ÌöyžÏ3ÙæqS¼#Ìâù÷¡æ{;Â<Ï¤#Ìâ3Ùô<Ï¤#Ìövúgsœó9ÿüÏ:s›èsŸ‚/„yÎyžÎðó=ÿü(A…ÂøþyáGð‚ÿð¡ÿÿðÿÿÿ|(þxøAaøA„wáÿòïÇÿä'B;ÿú_„g°‹þoÿ ïÂ
                                                        ïá!Â
                                                           , °‚ð‚Ãá<ó>î^AØpÂžg¸Aay½ŽCŸøg¿ñü„7â¾l/ð‚øAO3ðPü ‚
:xAcÃð‚Ê|B<Ï¦”øóÌî{>‚
                      ï
                       ïþsþs} AäüáaøACøA
                                        , ¡p/…á_ð°‚ÿÃ9ðøAÿÿø_ÂøAxA~Aÿáty?þ_æÿüßþÏœü8aÿÎxgïø‡à°Âðˆ0ŒÅ"á!úN0ð@ˆyÉ†aH0‚!îì„¿ÿæÂrnÿ
                                                                                                                                “ä\#Á0Â<""""""""""""""""""""†ÊÐ`ÃƒÃÁ·ÃÛvØpÏn‚#Ì8»D|·vÛaÓ
†G    0Ãˆl0s.a†pÑ0í°Ão[•6
“c<Ž¥ºª
     838—Á²:†Q±œÙÍŒÂ#¢?hŽ¡¢:#òÜÎàÎoSQa¶áÃ`ÌÔ
‘û:        0qg:# `ì60pØaƒÎ`î`ÁÄ†Áƒ†RˆüCDt9œÃÐn´pÎpÃD
   C†Q                                        æøCMˆÚ#Ñ#â
      8‘Ó                                               ÍA{
         ;(€Á¢=g!†ì2l;‰                                    ìM9¼ñf Ù6/ƒ32ÎÎn€áœÝÃ9ºˆ35+&ÂH0â
                       0vpØ0pÊÐ0hYômÄŽ˜`ÈÚåB                                               ÍB  °¦ÑaÄš–M‹qf¡©6@Ê¦™‘Ón“e4šdŒÆâ0eˆMLHèm0Q&êù6JØ8“r|›lIºNm00aÉ¿`ÌÓV ÎMÏ†[L`ƒ‘Õ‡&õ `ø0âGÃÍÄŒÓÀÊ7;NŽƒ-¤hÊ7%ÐaÄŽ–ÒXe”
                                                   ›\8—@Ëi2Êq:³´‹      ¹b
                                                        °Ãƒ               ¡ÎÒ(>!¤,á™¤&ÎvØg73Hè0â
                                                           0á†                                    Í%Ýa;H‰†f•AÈê6GRÈjƒ$tMÕh†šC†å’h33L™ÍÉC‰už$tÁÄpe³BË"t
ƒá»1²ƒ5•C                                                     °`á†8aƒD~ØhŽ¡°ÁØ0`àØr:†cdáÛGáÃe›                                                        ;9ºXq.™šTÎn—#¨em`¶hÃaÈü0Á²:¶
          ÌÑ0Ã–A¤       C†
                 ÌÐ!      pØdšÃb
                    82™¤Ë ®$z ÎÍ™µƒ;7PÌÍ C”Í£q#ðÎÍ€ÎÍ33
Ãøg6*Dua†Aƒ–á2mRVs`³5U1°P83›paÙ”Ê¦©P3›)2:ˆ4Gå¸²#¡aDGxlÁ˜–Ù‹a–Ì%Gá”l.Ìl.6
 ¦b›-˜                                            ¶¨ÛDt8³›"?l[‰0{&Ëuƒ

82‡)˜TðËf
                Pp`ááœr™„Æ0á¸ff'veMÃ;00Î9LÊàÎÌàÎ9LÇ,°‰B
                                                       ã”Îf,ìƒ$u:n!¸fgXfuPggS
                                                                             ÌáMÁœµÈüC(r™ÅÞÇ)œL0àäu;O  †PægVØ†í†S8FÙ™Ä6
                                                                                                                        Ìõ¶Ë ªft
                                                                                                                                A”9LómÈü0Ãv0á†på‘ÐaØ1v„°Ã
                                                                                                                                                         í
                                                                                                                                                          a†ÚC
ˆgh(ÃveSB“bÎÐl8a†îh0É¹šv‚¡
    0Ì9Ml0n`ÌÐdÜÉ)0ÙLº”9Ú†ÄC)¡C
                               Hô0Á”Ð00Ùm†jVˆêÛpaƒ;Ea™£ƒ
òlD                                                     C”Ñ†,ã”Êh
   8lNG3(@ÊeXlDYÇ)•P0Æ†
                       ¡Êe
                          1e2‚tËe*l›­¢Ê*¡ƒ[(«eob
                                                 Ì£A†YðgelC)”À`ÙC”9L¡‚G†Å™”C`ÎÊ¢>YfeÔ6$t
                                                                                          ã”Ê€Ø‹;-eMPå2ðlXv
                                                                                                            µ
                                                                                                             CbÎÈhÙdAÈ0Ä2ÙŠÞe¨¢Û3! l³ŠàÎÈ¨Ã,‚hC(r™Ú#¡+‹(s²†ˆùdÄC)±±e²0ËQf†ÁM°Ê¦A¦dBÎÈD|C;"FÃ3"€ÃfBí‰Ô6Ã°Ë ¢,£jØ³ŽS!Ãa¢?aˆgdæÃ)“
                                                                         HêÙdÄ¿lDÃD|3ŽQºËe]0ÄŽ»læó*@f7S
                                                                                                          1HHý±
ÛÎ9Fá                                                                                                          £pPÛ)Ê7+aŠVÄŽá†Z¥øl2ÅlæâFE;aœÜhCDtÌ0Ë!J
     7aƒ9¸€Øg7NÙd*A”oXaˆ‘øhŽƒ9¹
                               0Ë7˜lvnØÃ
                                        ²"Ê«‘Õ±sc0Øg6Ka–B¤FÉA†$tÌl²Øƒ(Ù`0Ù•[,…H7
                                                                                 6vU£›)4GÄ2‚ÃbGPØ‘û
†Q²@ÑB¤$zÃg6.#áœØB¤Í«Ä3›jÃ,…(3ŽQ²DtÎÊ¬å{                                                           3BGPÃ,…)”l,âÊ£a0Ùd,BÎl6ÃÎl†sc
                                         Rf6˜lAœÛš#¢ÈT˜vƒ(ÚDtY
Ð‘Õ²ÈT™Û’†vêË!ZŽ…á†$u
                ¡ÊnÎÈTS@gn
L…ESB²mRB›–ÙÛ•‹!^Û”3µVJn.l…4jvâa¢:Èè0pÑtÃ…      2š*Ø†a‡GEY7r:Ã†ˆùdÃhŽƒ)¢·ÎÑXpÎ9L‚Å4'pÃ:
                                                                                        0Å¸hŽƒrÈ-‡.¡œsµVpÓš«AÃdt
                                                                                                                6pÁ†ˆü9dMÛ.™M
8°pÙ
0á™ª´0eÂåÔ2Ú«HŽ¡Ë Þ0pÊd)¡[™3µRÃˆgj¥¸g¦ªË‡#àÁÃE
         89è7hCpÌÕZr:aÃ‘ÑdHƒpÑt!¢?i‡
                                    ¶ªË†Ë"M‡
                                            †4GA»
†áœrš«á†Y¦¡¡                                     0àá‡g¦Bgh0¡Å“‘fj¬‡
Ðghpì;†[UT©l°ƒ&ÕUvVÔ˜aÄebAÃ8å5IQ†Æš¤í–@xhÃdtMn#¡.ƒÃe4
Œ3ŽS\Ì0á²Éª†
            KB¯n
                ÃDu`àÝ‡7d)˜¬f
Ãd¥a†áÈè3³¸eµë               1†á–×GE’Šc
”ÌpÃƒ
     ²QYšÆA‡
            8a–OW#¡#¨mœ°8ÙlžS9Hla‡xgk[X¡¢:‡†fL)œ       Èèa‡GPÙd…
                                                                 1†
                                                                   ²ðÑtÝ¡†vAÎÏXeµªGPÑtMÌÕ¢>0ðÃ&éju
Û†qÊ7S) ”60e5JÚ¢Á–Õ                                                                               ÍaÁ”9MS6áƒ†áìíU€Î9MU@ðÊrš¡O
-¨”#¨³µXw#¨n       8jÎå5Rƒ;U[ÙmRá¢:Œ8`àäur:‹;V™«ÅrÔÑE¸2š°ÎÕ3µ
            ÆãE4TÃn
                   íBÆá™¨PpÃƒ)¨&$z
                                  qÊj
Ã;L˜gi¨                              87aÄXpx‘Ôe˜±Ã8å5 9Fá¦fM3"È­      ˆfi¬šjA¸fi‚;L°3´Ê„Û†qÊi‰
       í0a¦ 34ëSN¦f˜`ÌÓ8lŽ£pÌÓ‡#¨aÃpfi%2Òú%Õ™¤Êí"Ñ
                                                   í"°Êi2‡)¤.Ã‰uNpÙ6PÎÒHÚJÃ+f§fƒf\ÌíÁs,3´«
                                                                                           Í-‘ÔYC”Ò£Ã2à…4(På4 x‘øe.[@êðÌÍ[
                                                                                                                          82™«
                                                                                                                              ¦i(‘è2™ªLÌÐPÙ‡†0á¸gfŠ2lÑ aÃpÃƒ;5CpÎÍ.LÑ]YÙº†På3HS”Í˜ áá›l†a˜g¦bØr:gf†vb¨g¦`XaÃ‘Ô<Hý¸ff
                                                          á™˜$pÃƒ;1 gf+
                                                                       ã”Ì.Ü¦eA¨gfj™„á™™0e3=™ƒ-C.Ä‹n¬×Ã2*†eáCiÔHðÈêLêB]Ylå`ñ#«38°3³Š7
                                                                                                                                        Ìã@ÊgfgH$tGV¬¡Êg."GVfzƒÄŽˆêäu
Œ3³Àe´pÌÐ”pÜHü2šYÚÃ)aR<0ÁÃgh
Ã;A0ÎÐ 2‡;@                 ã”Ð&/Å‡
            ¦‚GVM €n
                     í`àÃƒ3@íÔYl©e¯jÎÊ´l¤…®…geS
                                               ¡Êe
,Ð¼Y‡)”¬E”¤´–÷#¨Hn"Gì832
                          µÅh3²„
ÄCeq¥                          ¡Ê7Ny‹;*pÌË¨3²†ÙPl¾
      ¶C"Ø…e²,–ÄÕ”9C”È¦-ÔYC”È
Äº³2Êd+fd(vA`Ì9LƒcpÎÈ™  ƒ;"€Ëd
    ¶JÙl˜[      HŽ­ø†ss0Ê72?aÁœÜ”3í(¦ë!œÝL3›…‰DŽˆê,æå!˜ÜXHèŽ­Æ["|3p‚Gâ]YFõ      ‰ÔF[+J&”n8—â]YFËB_†se@Ê]ÊP—ÆÍ‹F[@è‘øe
        Í€ƒ9²@Ê£eÊ&8e$~9m,(‘øg6/Æ[n¢]G-°ÔHê9L£-µj2ÛQ.£ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿø€
endstream
endobj
8 0 obj
4041
endobj
xref
0 9
0000000000 65535 f
0000000016 00000 n
0000000068 00000 n
0000000253 00000 n
0000000317 00000 n
0000000493 00000 n
0000000611 00000 n
0000000629 00000 n
0000004913 00000 n
trailer
<<
/Size 9
/Root 1 0 R
/Info 2 0 R
/ID[<67458B6BC6237B3269983C6473483366><67458B6BC6237B3269983C6473483366>]
>>
startxref
4933
%%EOF
[root@cloud01 tmp]#
```

Am I missing a library or some other dependency?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tiff2pdf):

> tiff2pdf opens a TIFF image and writes a PDF document to **standard output**.

Perhaps if you tried:

```
tiff2pdf FAX-443439791001-2015-09-26_00-34-40.tiff > FAX-443439791001-2015-09-26_00-34-40.pdf
```

Comment: That was simple. Thanks very much